# Can HTable.get(List<Get>) ever put null references in the returned array?

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, hbase

The HBase Javadoc is very confusing for the HTable.get(List) method.

As return parameter documentation, we have the following statement:

```
If there are any failures even after retries,
there will be a null in the results array for those Gets,
AND an exception will be thrown.
```

I don't understand the "AND": we can either have an exception or a null in the returned array, not both at the same time like the documentation implies.

I never heard of a Java method that was able to both raise an exception and return something.

I handle exceptions in my code when I call this method, but do I also have to worry about null references in the result array?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here is misleading, since this function does not return results and throw an error at the same time in case of failure.

I digged this up because I was confused as well.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/432e0d3044d5eaf78d0b7da5ed8fe3dba3c00508/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/AbstractBigtableTable.java#L228-L245) of this function:

```java
  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public Result[] get(List<Get> gets) throws IOException {
    LOG.trace("get(List<>)");
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(gets);
    if (gets.isEmpty()) {
      return new Result[0];
    } else if (gets.size() == 1) {
      try {
        return new Result[] {get(gets.get(0))};
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw createRetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException(e, gets.get(0));
      }
    } else {
      try (Scope scope = TRACER.spanBuilder("BigtableTable.get").startScopedSpan()) {
        addBatchSizeAnnotation(gets);
        return getBatchExecutor().batch(gets);
      }
    }
  }
```

Okay, so in case of a list of more than a single item, it calls [`getBatchExecutor().batch(gets)`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/432e0d3044d5eaf78d0b7da5ed8fe3dba3c00508/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BatchExecutor.java#L232-L246), that function is defined like so:

```java
  public Result[] batch(List<? extends Row> actions) throws IOException {
    try {
      Object[] resultsOrErrors = new Object[actions.size()];
      batchCallback(actions, resultsOrErrors, null);
      // At this point we are guaranteed that the array only contains results,
      // if it had any errors, batch would've thrown an exception
      Result[] results = new Result[resultsOrErrors.length];
      System.arraycopy(resultsOrErrors, 0, results, 0, results.length);
      return results;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      LOG.error("Encountered exception in batch(List<>).", e);
      throw new IOException("Batch error", e);
    }
  }
```

See the comment there:

> At this point we are guaranteed that the array only contains results, if it had any errors, batch would've thrown an exception

Which means this function will only raise an IOException in case of a failure with no further information on results. But then, how do you find out about failed and properly processed items of a batch? Turns out there is [another version of the function `batch` defined on `Table`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/432e0d3044d5eaf78d0b7da5ed8fe3dba3c00508/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/AbstractBigtableTable.java#L180-L187) that supports this case:

```java
  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void batch(List<? extends Row> actions, Object[] results)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    LOG.trace("batch(List<>, Object[])");
    try (Scope scope = TRACER.spanBuilder("BigtableTable.batch").startScopedSpan()) {
      addBatchSizeAnnotation(actions);
      getBatchExecutor().batch(actions, results);
    }
  }
```

And the corresponding [definition](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/432e0d3044d5eaf78d0b7da5ed8fe3dba3c00508/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BatchExecutor.java#L259-L291) in `BatchExecutor`:

```java
  public void batch(List<? extends Row> actions, @Nullable Object[] results)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    batchCallback(actions, results, null);
  }
  public <R> void batchCallback(
      List<? extends Row> actions, Object[] results, Batch.Callback<R> callback)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(
        results == null || results.length == actions.size(),
        "Result array must have same dimensions as actions list.");
    if (actions.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }
    if (results == null) {
      results = new Object[actions.size()];
    }
    Timer.Context timerContext = batchTimer.time();
    List<ApiFuture<?>> resultFutures = issueAsyncRowRequests(actions, results, callback);
    // Don't want to throw an exception for failed futures, instead the place in results is
    // set to null.
    List<Throwable> problems = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Row> problemActions = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultFutures.size(); i++) {
      try {
        resultFutures.get(i).get();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        problemActions.add(actions.get(i));
        problems.add(e.getCause());
        hosts.add(options.getDataHost());
      }
    }
    if (problems.size() > 0) {
      throw new RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException(problems, problemActions, hosts);
    }
    timerContext.close();
  }
```

With this function, you pass in an (empty) `results` array the size of your batch in, and this array gets filled as results come in. In the end, if any of the items in the batch fail, there will be an exception with details on why they failed, but still your `results` array is filled with results of all items. Failed items will be `null` in that array while the rest contain an actual `Result`.